# Improving visualization of streets intersections in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, visualisation, streets

I need to improve the street network intersections.
The image describes what I want.
These streets are all on the same level (elevation).

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Have you tried Dissolve?

Comment: I am using ArcMap. I cannot use Dissolve, because I am placing labels (streetnames) as well.

Comment: You could keep one dissolved layer on top of the undissolved.

Comment: Yes! I could do that! Maybe it will be a 'heavy' map, but I'll give it a try! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using Symbol Level Drawings in ArcMap.

Symbol levels is an advanced option in symbology that allows us to control how line features connect to each other. This allows us to show joins and intersection in a better way. We can see the intersecting lines being merged and joined together.

I remember this from one of my activities, and I also have the saved MXD, I am sharing my results below, and as per my understanding, this is what you are trying to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Kindly follow the below link for a better understanding.

[What is symbol level drawing](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/what-is-symbol-level-drawing-.htm#:%7E:text=Using%20symbol%20level%20drawing%2C%20you,the%20context%20of%20other%20symbols.)

Comment: This must be it! However, I haven't yet been able to achieve it. I will let you know! Thank you very much!

Comment: Absolutely, let me know if you are stuck somewhere, I will guide you with the steps :)
This needs to be done from the advanced options of Symbology.

Comment: The 'symbol levels' was the answer! Thank you all, and especially @Yogesh Chavan for pointing it out! [More about symbol levels here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/what-is-symbol-level-drawing-.htm#:%7E:text=Using%20symbol%20level%20drawing%2C%20you,the%20context%20of%20other%20symbols.)